# Same crs, different spatial reference system units, shape files / QGIS

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system

I have two files, same crs but different reference system units and different scale. Long story short, the shp files won't overlap :(

I've read some answers to what seems to be the same problem but I just can't fix it.

Layer 1
Layer Spatial Reference System:
WGS 84 / UTM 21S
In layer spatial reference system units:
xMin,yMin 368398.86,6105694.51 : xMax,yMax 852832.93,6265658.88

Layer 2
Layer Spatial Reference System:
WGS 84 / UTM 21S
In layer spatial reference system units:
xMin,yMin -57.9891,-36.9946 : xMax,yMax -50.0697,-34.4732

Can someone help me with this problem?

Comment: Looks like your bounding boxes are in completely different areas, so the areas won't overlap. What have you already attempted that did not fix the issue?

Comment: I read answers to similar questions but somehow I couldn't figure out how to fix my own problem! I'm not an expert, even thought I use GIS quite often, so I keep learning every time :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The second layer seems to be in degrees, although the SRS tells something else.

So you might set `EPSG:4326 WGS84` with `Set Layer CRS`.

The result looks reasonable:

[image]

Comment: @gonz.c Just to be explicit, the problem is that the CRS for the second layer was *wrong*. Even though it said UTM 21S, the data itself was actually in long/lat. So all you did was correct the CRS, without changing anything in the data.